# developed torque in electric motors

Tags: motor

In a motor what is meant by developed torque?
Is it the input to the motor?
Or the the output at the shaft?

I know there are losses in a motor but I don't know which torque is the one developed?

Similarly what is developed power?

***I only changed machine to motor to make the question more precise.***

Comment: Torque at the shaft can be either input to or output from the machine.

Comment: Generally the term "developed torque" when applied to an electrical machine is referring to the OUTPUT torque at the shaft.  But there may be variations depending on the specific machine.  If you have a specific reference here you might post that.  It's the torque developed as a result of operating the machine.  If the output is stalled  you will still have torque and input power but there will be no output power since there is no rotation of the shaft.

Comment: @jwh20 I edited the question. for a motor developed means IN or OUT?

Comment: Developed usually just means output power under specific conditions. For an induction motor, running with no load, it spins faster than rated speed (low slip). As the load increases, the slip increases, the output torque increases, and the input current increases. So in a sense, the output power is "developed"  as the load increases.